# increment value inside an array of arrays (if key is non-existent, set it to 1)

Tags: php, arrays

**Question has been updated to clarify**

For simple arrays, I find it convenient to use `$arr[$key]++` to either populate a new element or increment an existing element.  For example, counting the number of fruits, `$arr['apple']++` will create the array element `$arr('apple'=>1)` the first time "apple" is encountered.  Subsequent iterations will merely increment the value for "apple".  There is no need to add code to check to see if the key "apple" already exists.

I am populating an array of arrays, and want to achieve a similar "one-liner" as in the example above in an element of the nested array.

`$stats` is the array. Each element in `$stats` is another array with 2 keys ("name" and "count")

I want to be able to push an array into `$stats` - if the key already exists, merely increment the "count" value.  If it doesn't exist, create a new element array and set the count to 1.  And doing this in one line, just like the example above for a simple array.

In code, this would look something like (but does not work):

```
$stats[$key] = array('name'=>$name,'count'=>++);
or 
$stats[$key] = array('name'=>$name,++);
```

Looking for ideas on how to achieve this without the need to check if the element already exists.

Background:

I am cycling through an array of objects, looking at the "data" element in each one.  Here is a snip from the array:

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [to] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => foobar
                                [id] => 1234
                            )

                    )

            )
```

I would like to count the occurrences of "id" and correlate it to "name". ("id" and "name" are unique combinations - ex. name="foobar" will always have an id=1234)

i.e.

```
id     name   count
1234  foobar    55
6789  raboof    99
```

I'm using an array of arrays at the moment, `$stats`, to capture the information (I am def. open to other implementations.  I looked into `array_unique` but my original data is deep inside arrays & objects).

The first time I encounter "id" (ex. 1234), I'll create a new array in `$stats`, and set the count to 1.  For subsequent hits (ex: id=1234), I just want to increment `count`.

For one dimensional arrays, `$arr[$obj->id]++` works fine, but I can't figure out how to push/increment for array of arrays.  How can I push/increment in one line for multi-dimensional arrays?

Thanks in advance.

```
$stats = array();
foreach ($dataArray as $element) {
  $obj = $element->to->data[0];
  // this next line does not meet my needs, it's just to demonstrate the structure of the array
  $stats[$obj->id] = array('name'=>$obj->name,'count'=>1);

  // this next line obviously does not work, it's what I need to get working
  $stats[$obj->id] = array('name'=>$obj->name,'count'=>++);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that $array[$key]++ works fine if $key doesn't exist in the array? I've not found a way around using an isset() if condition. This ugliness really irks me since I come from a perl background where you can ++ or pretty much do anything else to a non existent array index and have it created on the fly.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich yes, I use it often. php 5+ and 7+

Comment: It throws a warning. The least you need to do is suppress it with `@` which is even more nasty

Answer (score 2):

Try checking to see if your array has that value populated, if it's populated then build on that value, otherwise set a default value.

```
$stats = array();
foreach ($dataArray as $element) {
    $obj = $element->to->data[0];
    if (!isset($stats[$obj->id])) { // conditionally create array
        $stats[$obj->id] = array('name'=>$obj->name,'count'=> 0);
    }
    $stats[$obj->id]['count']++; // increment count
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement something similar to the one liner `$arr[$obj->id]++`but for multi-dimensional arrays?  My original code is very similar to your suggestion above (it works) and wanted to see if I could lose a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Just edited answer with a slighly shorter version where you increment the count with the "++" and get rid of the `$count` variable. What exactly do you mean for multi-dimensional arrays, `$stats` is a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

`$obj = $element->to->data` is again an array. If I understand your question correctly, you would want to loop through $element->to->data  as well. So your code now becomes:

```
$stats = array();
foreach ($dataArray as $element) {
  $toArray = $element->to->data[0];

  foreach($toArray as $toElement) {

    // check if the key was already created or not
    if(isset($stats[$toElement->id])) {
      $stats[$toElement->id]['count']++;
    }
    else {
      $stats[$toElement->id] = array('name'=>$toArray->name,'count'=>1);
    }
  }
}
```

Update:
Considering performance benchmarks, isset() is lot more faster than array_key_exists (but it returns false even if the value is null! In that case consider using `isset() || array_key exists()` together.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#107786

Comment: Is there a way to implement something similar to the one liner `$arr[$obj->id]++`but for multi-dimensional arrays?  My original code used the `isset` function as you show in your suggestion above (it works) and wanted to see if I could lose a couple of lines of code.

Comment: limeygent Please explain more on `multi dimensional`. I am unable to understand this part of your question

Comment: I updated my question to help clarify.  I might be asking for a solution that is not supported and will implement using the logic you and blad describe.