# Rgd Array Push that increment by 1

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array such as this

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Grilled n salted
    [1] => Chilli con carne
    [2] => Chilli con carne
    [3] => Grilled n salted
    [4] => Homemade Spanish
    [5] => Yoghurt baked
    [6] => Grilled n salted
    [7] => Slow-cooked dory
)
```

I would like to from the array, I am able to form a new array which

```
[0]
[name]Grilled n salted
[amt]3

[1]
[name]Chilli con carne
[amt]2

[2]
[name]Homemade Spanish
[amt]1

[3]
[name]Yoghurt baked
[amt]1

[4]
[name]Slow-cooked dory
[amt][1]
```

How do I reassemble the array above to form an array with name, and amt based on the repeat sequence of the previous array. on the top

**Thanks!**

Comment: Have you tried something ? And please also show your **exact** expected output. Should that be one array or what?

Comment: @Rizier123 I had tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393983/increment-value-inside-an-array-of-arrays-if-key-is-non-existent-set-it-to-1 but it doesn't work out the way, my integer doesn't increment.

Comment: @Rizier123 the expected output is at the post, its a 1 dimension array.

Comment: ^ Then add the code, which you have tried into your question + the current output from it. And show how it is different from your expected output, and where you are stuck to change it.

Comment: Well if your array should be only 1 and also 1 dimensional, you will run into the problem, that every key must be unique, so there can't be 2x the key name or amt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$c = array_count_values($arr);
foreach($c as $k => $v) $b[] = array('name' => $k, 'amt' =>$v);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Grilled n salted
            [amt] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Chilli con carne
            [amt] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Homemade Spanish
            [amt] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Yoghurt baked
            [amt] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Slow-cooked dory
            [amt] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: This  doesn't seems to match the expected output from OP, besides, that it is a code only answer.

Comment: @Rizier123 I added result. I so understood   the question. But maybe i'm wrong

Comment: Well I think a 1 dimensional array is pretty technical and clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763397/rgd-array-push-that-increment-by-1/30763711?noredirect=1#comment49579335_30763397

Comment: oh! i don't uderstand 1 dimentional  array of such structure as in the question